# Request Cookies domain shows "N/A" in Developer Tools

Tags: google-chrome, http, cookies, google-chrome-devtools

In Chrome's Developer Tools, on the Network Tab, I noticed the Request Cookies' domain is always set to "N/A". This is not correct, right? I think the domain of the cookie should be the domain of the URL (in the GET request).

[image]

Comment: Were you able to figure out why its happening ? I see similar issue, but doesnt happen always.